# get list of filelds from of any given Class (Type) as a passed parameter

Tags: c#, reflection

i would like to convert a method that already does the job

(only if you instantiate the class within its body)

to one that will accept the subjected class as a passed parameter...somehow.

i have tried to get that result by my self by trial and error ,
(mostly trial ..and errors , lots...)

but no success (:

this first class is within my helpers classes (the extensions namespace)

```C#
public static List<string> AnyClassFieldsValuesAsList<T>(this T Clss, string nestedName)
{
    // i know how to get this to work... if an instace of the class is declared 
    // only here i would like to have any given class...as passed parameter
    // couple of tests to get a hold of the passed Class...no success (:
    var T1 = typeof(T.GetType());
    var T2 = Clss.GetType();

    return typeof(Clss.GetType()).GetFields(); //ToList<string>();
}
```

this is the subjected class (that i have stored in same helpers file) to hold strings representing style-fonts

```C#
public class FontNames 
{
    public readonly string Aharoni = "Aharoni",
                           Andalus = "Andalus",
                           AngsanaNew = "Angsana New",
                           AngsanaUPC = "AngsanaUPC",
                           Aparajita = "Aparajita";
                           //.....etc'
}
```

now within the **code behind** of the current project i want to be able to do something like

```
//imports of extensions and my style namespaces ....
// then somewhere after Page_Load()...

var instnceOfFnames  = new FontNames();
list<string> FontsLst= instnceOfFnames.AnyClassFieldsValuesAsList(.....);
```

parameters in signature of `AnyClassFieldsValuesAsList()` at the top are just for testing,

as i couldn't work with them, i am not sure that they are the ones that i should pass.

**what is the correct syntax to achive the results ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood, you need to get the fields' values without an instanse of the class. I suppose, you should declare those fields as `public readonly static ...`. Then you'll be able to utilize the following method:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFields<T>()
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    return type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                .Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(string))
                .Select(f => (string)f.GetValue(null));
}
```

like this:

```
foreach (string f in GetFields<FontNames>())
     Console.WriteLine(f);
```

---

Based on comments:

For the current issue (as far as I understand it), it seems to be superfluos, as static fields do not need instances to be accessed. But at least it can give some ideas

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFields<T>(this T value)
{
    Type type = value.GetType();
    //...all the same as above
}
```

To get the same result it's enough to have the same without generics

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFields(this object value)
{
    Type type = value.GetType();
    //...all the same as above
}
```

Comment: @kosta zdravstvuy...(;
do you know how to turn it into extension method do you have another version of this approach in mind ?(it works as it is ...by the way)

Comment: or.. the way with your sggustion , dose not actually requiers one ..as it's simple to implement like it is, just put the given class name ...as parameter... so if i will do like the way you suggested(public static ...) it is not even required as an extension version would not give benefits

Comment: @LoneXcoder extension methods require an instanse of an object as the first parameter, that is senseless for static fields. But if you had an instanse of the target class and needed to do the same thing you could change it a little bit. I'll update my answer...

Comment: i was checking both Ienumerable<string> vs List<string> , the results are towards List<T>  by far , its 30x faster 10K iterations over 200 fileds (strings aventually) , could it be ? http://venkyshandbook.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/ienumerable-vs-list.html